# Cannont run PyGlossary on Windows10

Tags: python-3.x

Absolute noob here, so I apologize in advance for stupid questions.

I'm running Windows 10, I've got Python 3.7.3 and I have...

> Successfully installed pyglossary-3.2.1

But I cannot run [PyGlossary](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary) from the command line or the tkinter GUI. If I run any of the following lines

`python3 pyglossary.pyw --help`

`python3 pyglossary.pyw --ui=tk`

`python3 pyglossary.pyw --version`

Nothing happens and I don't get any sort of error message. I've also tried...

`python pyglossary.pyw --help`

and I get...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "pyglossary.pyw", line 30, in 
> from pyglossary import core  # essential
> File "C:\mypath\pyglossary\pyglossary.pyw", line 30, in 
> from pyglossary import core  # essential
> ImportError: cannot import name 'core' from 'pyglossary' (C:\mypath\pyglossary\pyglossary.pyw)

I've checked Windows Path variables, but I think everything's ok there, and I'm able to run other python stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"or the tkinter GUI"_ what happens, when run on tkinter

Comment: My understanding is that the line `python3 pyglossary.pyw --ui=tk` is what runs pyglossary on tkinter (according to the link I pasted above) but nothing happens -no error message, no GUI pops up. Maybe I got it all wrong.

Comment: Im not sure about that, i actually dont know what pyglossary is for, maybe just try making a gui and importing it and use its functionalities?